# How can I log in into my not-registered SO account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is it possible to log in into my unregistered SO account after I log off ?

I don't want to merge it with existing account, I don't want it to have anything with my registered account. Imagine that I have only that unregistered account. I created it when answering a question. I just gave it some name and e-mail. Than I logged off and now I want to log in to leave a comment.

Comment: ...Why do you want to?  The only reason I can come up with is sockpuppeting, and I don't think they want to encourage that...

Comment: @Margaret Why do I want what ? Why do I want to comment on my answer ? Or why I don't want to merge with my account? You can sockpuppet with registered accounts as well as with unregistered... The is no problem to get some 10 openID... I just wanted to have second account lets say for "answers to beginers questions" (well not exactly but lets say)... And create it from that unregistred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as long as you provided a valid e-mail address when you posted the answer. Go to the [Account Recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) page and give it the e-mail address of the account you want to recover. You'll get an e-mail that has a link that will give you a new cookie for that account. Since unregistered accounts are entirely cookie-based, you'll need to do that every time you get logged out (so it really is saner to just register it if you're going to be using it long-term)

Comment: That's a neat feature I was unaware of.

Comment: Thank you great answer. I had really no idea that it is possible and I was starting to be sure it is not. And if I wanted to merge it with my registered account ? Do I have to flag it for moderator attention or is there any "automatic" way ?

Comment: @drasto You need a mod to do it

Comment: Yesterday I set up an unregistered account to ask one question. I am not interested in merging the two accounts. I am not interested in rep. I only wanted some information. After many hours of silence, someone commented on my post but I cannot log in. I received an email from SE asking me to confirm my email address but the log in still failed, I get the error message **The complete signup link you just used is incomplete. Please try signing up again. If you're still having trouble, contact support.** So, what did I do wrong? I have not deleted my browser history.

Comment: I would ask a new question on MSE  but I know it would be closed as a duplicate of this one.