# How can I login to account that used before without OpenID?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I log in into my not-registered SO account ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83504/how-can-i-log-in-into-my-not-registered-so-account)

I asked a question that I'm trying to respond to now. I asked that before I registered with this account. Now how can I edit the question or respond to, etc?

Comment: Probably this is your other account - http://stackoverflow.com/users/702838/ryan-cooper

Answer (score 0):

Unregistered users are tracked by a long living browser cookie. So if you don't change PC/browser, don't trash cookies on browser shutdown, don't reinstall the OS and visit the site regularly, then you will be able to use the same account forever without the need to register your user account.

However, registering the account has the benefit that you will be able to login using the same account from everywhere in the world. If you register an account and leave a mail at team@stackoverflow.com with a link to your original unregistered account, then they will merge it for you and you will be able to gain access to your original posts again.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to restore an unregistered account's cookie if you provide SE with your email address.

Comment: this answer should be edited, per @wai 's (correct) comment